# set custom data attr to element using data() doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(".post-btn").data('ng-click=','postStatus()');
```

what's wrong with my code?

http://jsfiddle.net/HqmQ7/17/

Comment: Everything. Why are adding AngularJS directive via jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skip the equal sign, and use `attr`:

```
$(".post-btn").attr('ng-click','postStatus()');
```

However, I have to say, using jQuery to manipulate Angular stuff just seems wrong.

Comment: @scrowler Angular uses `nq-click` as an attribute, and I'm guessing that's what to OP wants to do.

Comment: Cool - no experience in Angular, sorry